# Switch case program in C

Tags: c

I am trying to add words to the file and I called the function in the switch case. However when I run it nothing is added to the file and the menu is called and shows up everytime there is multiple words. Example: the sentence I input would be

The boy is tall. Then this happens below

The (menu pops up)

boy (menu pops up)

is (menu pops up)

tall(menu pops up)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
void menu(){
                
    int choice;
    printf("\n\n\t\tfile learning\n\n\n");
                
    while(1)
    {   
        printf("1. Store the file \n");
        printf("2. Test 2\n");
        printf("3. Quit\n");
                
        printf("Enter your choice:");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
                
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
            store_file();
            break;
                        
        case 3:
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
            
void store_file(){
    char text[50];
    FILE *fptr;
            
    // use appropriate location if you are using MacOS or Linux
    fptr = fopen("program.txt","w");
            
    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");   
        exit(1);             
    }
            
    printf("Enter your text: ");
    scanf("%s",&text);
            
    fprintf(fptr,"%s",text);
    printf("Your file has successfully been created. ");
               
               
    if ((fptr = fopen("program.txt","r")) == NULL){
        printf("Error! opening file");
            
        // Program exits if the file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);
    }
               
    fscanf(fptr,"%s", &text);
    printf("Text in file = %s", text);
             
              
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&text);` just reads one word from the input, not the whole line. So when you go back to the menu, it tries to use the second word as the menu choice. Since it's not an integer this fails, and it gets stuck in the loop repeatedly trying to get a menu choice.

Comment: Don't use `scanf()` to get input from the user. Use `fgets()` to read a whole line, then `sscanf()` to parse it if necessary.

Comment: Still not getting it, it just loops the menu and says your file has been succesfully created

Comment: If `scanf()` can't parse the input, it doesn't update the `choice` variable. So it keeps the `1` value from the previous time, and calls `store_file()` again. You need to add error checking.

Comment: You should close the file opened for writing before opening the same file for reading.